# How can I disable an input device?

Tags: devices

I have a broken laptop built-in keyboard (The shift-button sometimes gets stuck down). I exclusively use an external keyboard, but the internal keyboard interferes with it. (I can not unplug the device.)

I can disable with `xinput`, but it becomes enabled again (see [Permanently disable keyboard](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/471114/4778)).

I have identified the device. (you need install `lsinput` e.g. with `apt install input-utils`).

```
sudo lsinput

/dev/input/event0
   bustype : BUS_I8042
   vendor  : 0x1
   product : 0x1
   version : 43841
   name    : "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
   phys    : "isa0060/serio0/input0"
   bits ev : EV_SYN EV_KEY EV_MSC EV_LED EV_REP
```

How to I disable it?

Answer (score 3):

Blacklisting it could be an option. Like, if that's going through the `atkbd` module and nothing else needs that particular module, just blacklist the module.

Otherwise, perhaps `unbind` is an option as well.

Lacking a laptop to test with, I hooked up a spare mouse to my system and then disabled it.

This is the mouse:

```
I: Bus=0003 Vendor=04f3 Product=0235 Version=0111
N: Name="OM"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-10.1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-10/2-10.1/2-10.1:1.0/0003:04F3:0235.0004/input/input12
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event12 mouse1 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=17
B: KEY=70000 0 0 0 0
B: REL=903
B: MSC=10
```

Going through `/sys/bus/hid/...`:

```
# head /sys/bus/hid/drivers/*/*/*/*/name
==> /sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-generic/0003:046A:010D.0001/input/input3/name <==
HID 046a:010d

==> /sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-generic/0003:046A:010D.0002/input/input4/name <==
HID 046a:010d

==> /sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-generic/0003:046D:C077.0003/input/input5/name <==
Logitech USB Optical Mouse

==> /sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-generic/0003:04F3:0235.0004/input/input12/name <==
OM
```

Well, let's kick it out.

```
# echo 0003:04F3:0235.0004 > /sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-generic/unbind
```

And it's gone. No longer moves the mouse cursor. No longer even listed as input device. It's really gone.

So you can do such things with `unbind`ing, and depending on which driver it uses, also blacklisting. The main problem is locating the correct name and place to unbind it, then automate with a custom udev rule. Otherwise if you pull the plug and put it back in, it's there and back again.

Comment: that said, a lot of laptops actually have servicable keyboards. so don't be too quick to rule out a hardware solution entirely. if replacing the keyboard is not an option (laptop too old) it might still be possible to fix or disable the offending key in the hardware specifically. but that's a question for a hardware forum...

Comment: That's an old-school AT keyboard on a PS2 port. While you can blacklist that, too, it won't be under HID devices, and I'm not sure if you can actually unbind it. But you can definitely blacklist it on boot.

Answer (score 2):

If looking on the USB level didn't turn up anything you can fix, then the next two things you can do is to "grab" it on the input layer level, or prevent it becoming active on the X level.

For the first,

```
evtest --grab /dev/input/event0 > /dev/null
```

or something similar should do the trick: The grab makes sure only the grabbing application receives events, i.e., X won't receive any.

For the second, add an `InputClass` section to your `xorg.conf`, along the lines of

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "BrokenKeyboard"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/by-path/platform-i8042-serio-0-event-kb"
    Option "Ignore" "true"
EndSection
```

assuming that this path is actually what links to your keyboard. Don't use `/dev/input/event0` etc. here, it's not guaranteed to be consistent across boots.

Comment: I tried adding  the section to `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-my-disable-yoga-keyboard.conf`, but with added `d` to path. Nothing happened. Am I doing it correct? Do I need to change the priority number of the file?

Comment: I would also like something that works outside of X11: console, wayland (I may use this).

Comment: Check via `Xorg.log` if the matching works, or you need to change it to something else. If you want something outside of X, you'll need to disable it on a lower layer, e.g. input or the kernel module itself as suggested in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Belated, but I wanted to expound upon the answers up above just a bit for Apple users. I have a MBP with a busted internal keyboard, and I've been using `evtest` to grab input from it and send it to `/dev/null`. This seems to be the most common suggestion floating around. The problem with this solution is that the event number changes if the kernel is updated, and if you have a script that runs at boot like I do, this number has to be manually updated with each kernel update. This is where using `unbind` comes in, and how the answer above inspired me to finally ditch `evtest`. I've come up with a simple one-liner, and it seems to do the job perfectly.

Here's the full command:

```
head /sys/bus/hid/drivers/*/*/*/*/name | grep "apple" | sed -E 's/[^0-9A-F:.]*//g' | awk '{ print substr( $0, 1, length($0)-2 ) }' > /sys/bus/hid/drivers/apple/unbind
```

We know what the first part of this does, so I'll explain the need for `sed` and `awk`. Running just `head` along with a `grep` will output something akin to this:

```
/sys/bus/hid/drivers/apple/0003:046D:C077.0003/input/input18/name
```

Now, we use `sed` to get rid of everything that's not a hexadecimal character:

```
0003:046D:C077.000318
```

You'll notice that the input number is also included on the end there, which we don't need, so we use `awk` to remove the last two characters of the string:

```
0003:046D:C077.0003
```

And of course, we have the output direction sending this string to `/sys/bus/hid/drivers/apple/unbind`. Plop this into a script that you can run at boot, and tada! The caveat to this is that it'll have to be modified for `hid-generic` devices. Apple has its own input driver directory that makes this a bit simpler, and `grep`'ing for just "apple" suffices.

Edit: This is the beauty of crowd-sourced information. Thanks go to Stephen Kitt down below for this solution. It's much more elegant than mine, and properly takes input device numbers into consideration.

```
for name in /sys/bus/hid/drivers/apple/*/*/*/name; do device=$(cut -d/ -f7 <<<"$name"); [ "$device" != "*" ] && printf "%s" "$device" > /sys/bus/hid/drivers/apple/unbind; done
```

Comment: What happens if the `input/inputX` part only has one digit? It would be more robust to look in the right directory instead of post-filtering, and then look at the relevant part of the path: `for name in /sys/bus/hid/drivers/apple/*/*/*/name; do device=$(cut -d/ -f7 <<<"$name"); [ "$device" != "*" ] && printf "%s" "$device" > /sys/bus/hid/drivers/apple/unbind; done`.

Comment: You're right! I'm not sure why I didn't think of that. Was a bit of a long day, and I was a little overly ecstatic. Thanks for the correction. :)

Comment: No worries, your answer is useful (I upvoted it); feel free to steal my comment and [edit] your answer to make it better ;-).